# sudo fdisk -l -u output does not show partitions

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, gparted, 17.04

I know this issue is common here, but mine has some specific terms that put me into the corner. So, I booted into liveUsb with Ubuntu, tried changing my partitions with Ubuntu installed to my PC and got the error "can't have overlapping partitions", then it crashed and after I rebooted to liveUSB, whole my hdd was shown as "unallocated". Now, when I am running `fdisk -l -u /dev/sda`, I get this output:

[image: Output]

So, does this mean that all my data is already erased? How is that even possible, when I simply tweaked partitions with ubuntu installed, and did not touch 800GB of other space?

Comment: Please do not use screenshots, instead copy and paste your code directly into your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you were working with your partitions you probably destroyed your partition table, or somehow made it unusable.

You can use a utility like `testdisk` in a live session to try bringing it back. your data still lives on the disk, so do not write anything on it.

[Test disk step by step](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step)

Comment: Indeed, the partition table  was unusable - some partitions were duplicated - i guess that's because GParted crashed and attempted to do teh same thing severaltimes. I was able to retreive all important files, but still it is frightening how easy it is to do such a thing with a GParted- my mistake was to delete Ubuntu booting my computer - but still i don't understand how the duplication was made

Comment: I'm not sure how this happened but I'm glad you could get your files back :)